# How to set a timeout for a login in C++?

Tags: c++, timer

I'm writing a timeout for a simple login on a server written in C++.
Well, this is the code:

```
char username[this->BUFSIZE];
    clean(username);
    char password[this->BUFSIZE];
    clean(password);
    send(client_fd, "USER", 4, 0);

    //Start timer
    time_t end,start;
    double dif;
    time (&start);

    recv(client_fd,username,BUFSIZE,0);
    send(client_fd, "PASS", 4, 0);
    recv(client_fd,password,BUFSIZE,0);

    //End timer
    time (&end);
    dif = difftime (end,start);
            //If dif>10 seconds disconnect the client.
    if(dif>10)
        close(client_fd);
```

Ok it works fine, but there is just a problem: the disconnect happens only when the client end typing user + password. My goal is that the timer must close the connection at 10 seconds, independently if the client did the login or not.

Is it possible?
Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you need a 'housekeeping' thread, running the background, checking and invalidating sessions independent of user actions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `select()` to wait for data on `client_fd`. `select` supports a timeout value and will return `0` if the timeout occurs. If data is ready, `select` will return the number of descriptors with data pending.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the socket option [SO_RCVTIMEO](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) with a `timeval` structure. This will cause recv to return once the timeout has happened.

Answer (score 0):

Use a signal - SIGALRM, set this before entering `recv` and when it triggers close the connection.

Alternatively use a full-fat framework such as asio, which will provide timers etc.